# How would you solve the differential equation; $~(4x^2+4y^2) dy + xy dx = 8~$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

How would you solve the differential equation; $$~(4x^2+4y^2) dy + xy dx = 8~?$$
Can you even do this question by substituting $~V= \dfrac{y}{x}~$ and solving from there?

Trying the get $~\dfrac{dy}{dx}~$ by itself is a tough ask too, so is this question insanely difficult? Or am I missing something simple?

Comment: This equation is impossible. On the left side you have an infinitesimal or a linear functional, on the right you have a constant. These are different types of objects that never can be equal.

Comment: I got this on a test... So for me to solve it, the right hand side would need to equal 0?

Comment: Yes. Could the 8 be a misprint or other deformation of a $0$ on the paper?

Comment: Hopefully, that was the only question that I couldn't answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It hasn't any solution since differentials equals to 8!

$dx,dy$ is near $0$ for every $x,y$, so the equality can't hold!

Answer (score 1):

If the right side were zero, you could group the left side by degrees
$$
[4x^2\,dy+xy\,dx] + 4y^2\,dy=0
$$
and contract to complete differentials
$$
0=\frac12y^{-7}\,d(x^2y^8)+4y^2\,dy=\frac12y^{-7}d\left(x^2y^8+\frac45y^{10}\right)
$$
This means that $10y^7$ is an integrating factor and
$$
5x^2y^8+4y^{10}=C
$$
are the solution curves.